# Passing struct to function in c

Tags: c, struct, inline-assembly

So, I am trying to add two vectors using some assembly code but I have problem with:

```
sse_vector4_add(set_vector(2,2,2,2),set_vector(4,2,4,2));
```

I am not sure how to pass those vectors to that function.

```
typedef struct vector4 {   
    float x, y, z, w;       
} vector4;

// Set values to a vector4
vector4 set_vector(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
    vector4 ret_vector = { x, y, z, w };
    return ret_vector;
}

// Use sse to add the elements of two vectors a + b
vector4 sse_vector4_add(vector4 *op_a,vector4 *op_b) {
    vector4 ret_vector;
    asm( 
        "mov %%eax,op_a \n"             // Load pointers into CPU regs
        "mov %%ebx,op_b \n"
        "movups %%XMM0,(%%EAX) \n"        // Move the vectors to SSE regs
        "movups %%XMM1,(%%EBX) \n"
        "addps  %%XMM0,%%XMM1 \n"       // Add elements
        "movups (ret_vector),%%XMM0 \n" // Save the return vector
        :
    );
    return ret_vector;
}

void main() {
    // Add two vectors
    sse_vector4_add(set_vector (2,2,2,2),set_vector(4,2,4,2));
    getchar();
}
```

Function `sse_vector4_add` was made from a similar function but in C++.

Comment: Unless you are in a freestanding environment, `main` returns `int`.

Comment: possibly an option is to modify the vector add function to take arguments by value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create variables, using `set_vector` to initialize them. Then, pass their addresses to the function.

```
vector4 a = set_vector(2,2,2,2);
vector4 b = set_vector(4,2,4,2);
vector4 c = sse_vector4_add(&a, &b);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it also be possible to return pointers to structs from `set_vector()` and send the pointer(s) to `sse_vector4_add()`?   So `vector4 *set_vector()` and then `sse_vector4_add(set_vector(...), set_vectcor(...));`

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I wasn't wanting to modify the existing interfaces. Also, you can't return pointers to function local variables. If you dynamically allocate, then the receiver has to deallocate. The existing interface is already pretty clean.

Comment: Understood - and yes you'd have to greatly modify the internals of the `set_vector()` for my suggestion to work.  I just wanted to mollify myself that I still grok pointers.